# Inserting data to SQL Server database in asp.net c#

Tags: c#, asp.net

I am inserting data into database using the following code. Neither it gives error nor it adds data to database. Am i missing anything in it?

The columns are `univ_regno` and `email` have datatype `nvarchar(50)` respectively

```
protected void btnSubmit_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    if (chkaccept.Checked)
    {
        try
        {
            con = new SqlConnection(ConfigurationManager.ConnectionStrings["SQL Connection String"].ConnectionString);
            con.Open();
            com = new SqlCommand("INSERT INTO stdtable ([univ_regno],[email]) values(@univ_regno,@email)", con);

            com.Parameters.Add("@univ_regno", txtuniv.Text);
            com.Parameters.Add("@email", txtemail.Text);

            com.ExecuteNonQuery();
            con.Close();

            /*show javascript message */
            Type cstype = this.GetType();
            ClientScriptManager cs = Page.ClientScript;
            String cstext = "alert('Record Added Successfully');";
            cs.RegisterStartupScript(cstype, "PopupScript", cstext, true);
        }
        catch (System.Exception err)
        {
           Type cstype = this.GetType();
           ClientScriptManager cs = Page.ClientScript;
           String cstext = "alert('"+  err.Message.ToString() +" ');";
           cs.RegisterStartupScript(cstype, "PopupScript", cstext, true);
        }
   }
   else
   {
       Type cstype = this.GetType();
       ClientScriptManager cs = Page.ClientScript;
       String cstext = "alert('Not checked ');";
       cs.RegisterStartupScript(cstype, "PopupScript", cstext, true);
   }
}
```

Comment: This shouldn't effect your specific problem, but you aren't closing your connections correctly.

Comment: What result does ExecuteNonQuery() return?

Comment: i am using con.Close(); is it not sufficient? @JoelCoehoorn

Comment: My guess is that there is an error in your javascript reporting. Set a break point in the `catch` to see what is actually happening with the sql call...

Comment: The connection **must always** be closed in a finally block, or you can end up creating a denial of service situation on your database.

Comment: Or better, wrap it in a `using`

Comment: @cadrell0 `using` works because the compiler expands it to a try/finally. Since he already has a try block here, just adding a finally is easier.

Comment: i have used finally but nothing happened.

Answer (score 1):

[image]    com.Parameters.Add("@univ_regno", txtuniv.Text);

does this add the value to the parameter? it calls the Parameters.Add(string name, SqlDbType type) overload

refer this link:

[Difference between Parameters.Add and Parameters.AddWithValue](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9999751/difference-between-parameters-add-and-parameters-addwithvalue)

Try adding parameters as

```
cmd.Parameters.Add("@univ_regno", SqlDbType.VarChar).Value = txtuniv.Text;
```

Comment: can u tell me that is there compulsary to declare scalar variable in sequence?

Comment: as i m adding data to univ_regno and email and adding parameters seqeuntially. can i email first and then univ_regno?

Comment: i think that wont be a problem.did you try changing the way you add parameters?use a break point and debug it line by line it may help

Comment: let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/18422/discussion-between-usman-and-karthi)