# Difference between SqlParameter.Add and AddWithValue

Tags: c#, .net, .net-3.5, sqlparameter

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [Difference between Parameters.Add and Parameters.AddWithValue](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9999751/difference-between-parameters-add-and-parameters-addwithvalue)

From MSDN code, what is the difference between these two:

```
    SqlCommand command = new SqlCommand(commandText, connection);

    //#1        
    command.Parameters.Add("@ID", SqlDbType.Int);
    command.Parameters["@ID"].Value = customerID;

    //#2
    command.Parameters.AddWithValue("@demographics", demoXml);
```

Is it better to do the first one to make sure I am casting the parameter corrctly? I'm trying to make my code more secure.

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/9999751/difference-between-parameters-add-and-parameters-addwithvalue

looks like the best answer i could find

Answer (score 4, accepted):

According to the [MSDN](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.data.sqlclient.sqlparametercollection.addwithvalue.aspx):

> AddWithValue replaces the SqlParameterCollection.Add method that takes
>   a String and an Object. **The overload of Add that takes a string and an
>   object was deprecated because of possible ambiguity with the
>   SqlParameterCollection**. Add overload that takes a String and a
>   SqlDbType enumeration value where passing an integer with the string
>   could be interpreted as being either the parameter value or the
>   corresponding SqlDbType value. **Use AddWithValue whenever you want to
>   add a parameter by specifying its name and value**.

So the `AddWithValue` replaces deprecated overload that create ambiguity.

Comment: so how does it handle the type now?

Comment: so don't use the first, only the second and ignore the type now is what microsoft is saying?

Comment: @chris: well, specifying a real type is always better, imo. What about this functions, it's just a simple substitude to the overload of the `Add`. In other words, it's kind of *refactoring* was done in framework to make API clear.

Answer (score 2):

Perhaps this rticle will help
http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.data.sqlclient.sqlparametercollection.addwithvalue.aspx