# update a field in database

Tags: c#, asp.net

I wrote this code to update a field in database but this field isn't updated.
I think the problem is related the find control cause I try that and it couldn't find my control.

C# code:

```
protected void btnCh_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    SqlConnection db = new SqlConnection(strcon);
    foreach (RepeaterItem repeaterItem in Repeater1.Items)
    {
        CheckBox CheckBox1 = (CheckBox)repeaterItem.FindControl("CheckBox1");
        if (CheckBox1.Checked)
        {
            db.Open();
            Label mylbl = (Label)repeaterItem.FindControl("mylbl");
            string mm= mylbl.Text;
            SqlCommand MyCMD = new SqlCommand("Update BuyGem Set GemChargeStatuse=1 ,Apple_gmail_Pass='' WHERE ID=@ID");
            MyCMD.Parameters.AddWithValue("@ID", mm);
            MyCMD.ExecuteNonQuery();
            db.Close();
        }
    }
}
```

Aspx code:

```
 <div class="col-md-12">
    <asp:Repeater ID="Repeater1" runat="server">
        <ItemTemplate>
            <div class="col-md-12">
                <div class=" pull-right  col-sm-6 animated2 bounceInLeft">
                    <div class="panel panel-primary ">
                        <asp:Label ID="mylbl" runat="server" ><%#Eval("ID")%></asp:Label>
                        <div class="panel-body" dir="rtl">
                            Name :
                            <asp:Label ID="lblname" runat="server"><%#Eval("Name") %></asp:Label>
                            <br />
                            <div class="col-md-9 pull-left col-xs-12 top15">
                                select:
                                <asp:CheckBox ID="CheckBox1" runat="server" />
                            </div>
                        </div>
                    </div>
                </div>
            </div>
        </ItemTemplate>
    </asp:Repeater>
    <asp:Button ID="btnCh" runat="server" Text="Button" OnClick="btnCh_Click" />
</div>
```

I should tell that the problem is not related to update command.I have tested and found out that the problem is related to findconrol that can't find any control in my repeater.please review your answers.

Comment: Soooo what's the problem? And have you step-through debugged your code?

Comment: What error/exception do you get?

Comment: I tried many way to find the problem.I didn't get any error just my field in data base isn't updated.

Comment: you missed the connection in command, see my answer.

Answer (score 1):

replace

```
 SqlCommand MyCMD = new SqlCommand("Update BuyGem Set GemChargeStatuse=1 ,Apple_gmail_Pass='' WHERE ID=@ID");
MyCMD.Parameters.AddWithValue("@ID", mm);
```

to

```
 SqlCommand MyCMD = new SqlCommand("Update BuyGem Set GemChargeStatuse=1 ,Apple_gmail_Pass='' WHERE ID=@ID",db);
MyCMD.Parameter.Add("@ID",SqlDbType.Int).Value=mm;
```

see [Difference between Parameters.Add and Parameters.AddWithValue](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9999751/difference-between-parameters-add-and-parameters-addwithvalue)

Comment: no it is not work.my connection and update command don't have any problem.

Comment: there isn't an error.just i can't find my controls so i can't update my table

Answer (score 0):

Is your ID parameter in the Database a varchar or integer?
Because currently

```
SqlCommand MyCMD = new SqlCommand("Update BuyGem Set GemChargeStatuse=1 ,Apple_gmail_Pass='' WHERE ID=@ID");
MyCMD.Parameters.AddWithValue("@ID", mm);
```

you are searching by string, where you shold be converting the string to integer like so:

```
int.Parse(idStringHere);
```

Answer (score 0):

MyCMD isn't associated with the db connection. Use something like:

```
var MyCMD = db.CreateCommand();
```

Comment: Put a try catch block around your code and see if any exceptions are being thrown. Also check the result of ExecuteNonQuery() to see if it is greater than 0. That method returns the number of rows that have been affected by the query, in this case it should be 1.

Comment: you know the problem is related to my findcontrol.i am sure