# C# calling User Defined Scalar function in SQL Server that takes table type as its Parameter

Tags: c#, sql-server, table-valued-parameters

I have been beating my head against a rock on this. I have written a scalar function that takes a table type I created as a parameter and it returns a simple varchar here is the sql code if it helps

```
ALTER FUNCTION [dbo].[pe_Get_Manufacturer]
(
-- Add the parameters for the function here
@Row [dbo].[pe_StringList] READONLY
)

RETURNS VARCHAR(103)
AS
BEGIN

DECLARE @OUT VARCHAR(50)
DECLARE @tempTable TABLE
(
    Position INT,
    ManuName CHAR(100),
    ManuCat CHAR(3)
)

INSERT INTO @tempTable
    SELECT DISTINCT r.Position, c.ima_mfg, c.ima_cat
    FROM dbo.[Admin_ MFR Aliases] as c
        INNER JOIN @Row r
            ON c.orig_mfg = r.Candidate 
            OR c.ima_mfg = r.Candidate
            OR c.orgmfgstrp = r.Candidate
    ORDER BY r.Position

SELECT TOP 1 @OUT = LTRIM(RTRIM(ManuName))  + '^' + COALESCE(ManuCat,'')
FROM @tempTable 
ORDER BY Position DESC

-- Return the result of the function
RETURN @OUT
END
```

on my C# side I have a funcation that takes is a list of strings that is to be put into a Datatable to to be used as the parameter for the function. I believe I have written this is all correctly how ever my project throws when it goes to run ExecuteScalar on the SQLCommand

```
public string getManufacturer(IList<string> list)
    {

        int counter = 1;
        DataTable dataTable = new DataTable();
        dataTable.Columns.Add("Position", typeof (int));
        dataTable.Columns.Add("Candidate", typeof (string));

        foreach (var candidate in list)
        {
            DataRow dataRow = dataTable.NewRow();
            dataRow["Position"] = counter++;
            dataRow["Candidate"] = candidate;
            dataTable.Rows.Add(dataRow);
        }

        SqlParameter tableType = new SqlParameter("@Row" , SqlDbType.Structured)
        {
            TypeName = "dbo.pe_StringList",
            Value = dataTable
        };

        string query = " SELECT * FROM dbo.pe_Get_Manufacturer(@Row)";

        SqlCommand sqlCommand = new SqlCommand(query, conn);
        sqlCommand.Parameters.AddWithValue("@Row", tableType);

        return sqlCommand.ExecuteScalar().ToString();

    }
```

This is the information I get from the exception:

"An exception of type 'System.ArgumentException' occurred in System.Data.dll but was not handled in user code

> Additional information: No mapping exists from object type
>   System.Data.SqlClient.SqlParameter to a known managed provider native
>   type."

EDIT----
this is the table type I created

```
CREATE TYPE pe_StringList
AS TABLE 
(
    Position INT,
    Candidate VARCHAR(50)
)
```

I changed the query from

```
string query = " SELECT * FROM dbo.pe_Get_Manufacturer(@Row)";
```

To

```
string query = " SELECT dbo.pe_Get_Manufacturer(@Row)";
```

Comment: What is the definition of the type pe_StringList? And does `SELECT * FROM dbo.pe_Get_Manufacturer(@Row)` work if called from withing SSMS?

Comment: What is `[dbo].[pe_StringList]`?

Comment: that is is the Table type I made

Comment: @MattC I added the definition of pe_stringList to the bottom of my question for you and I did update the query tot he correct one and yes it works in SSMS

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Simply change:

```
sqlCommand.Parameters.AddWithValue("@Row", tableType);
```

to be:

```
sqlCommand.Parameters.Add(tableType);
```

since it is already a `SqlParameter` type. You would use `AddWithValue` to create the `SqlParameter` on-the-fly (though please see my note at the bottom about not using that deprecated method), but you have already created the `SqlParameter` and just need to add it to the collection.

And yes, removing the `* FROM` from the query was also necessary from a purely T-SQL syntax stand-point.

---

Side note: it is best to not use `AddWithValue` in any case, ever ;-):

- [Difference between Parameters.Add and Parameters.AddWithValue](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9999751/difference-between-parameters-add-and-parameters-addwithvalue)
- [Can we stop using AddWithValue() already?](http://blogs.msmvps.com/jcoehoorn/blog/2014/05/12/can-we-stop-using-addwithvalue-already/)

Comment: Would be helpful if you explained this comment: `Side note: it is best to not use AddWithValue in any case, ever ;-).`

Comment: @MetroSmurf Was hoping to be lazy and not look up the reference :-p. But good call, so I added two links.

Comment: Hey it worked. Thanks a lot! It's comforting to know I wasn't way off.

Answer (score 0):

Try changing

```
sqlCommand.Parameters.AddWithValue("@Row", tableType);
```

to

```
sqlCommand.Parameters.AddWithValue("@Row", dataTable);
```

You're setting the value of the Parameter you're adding with value to a SqlParameter which is not needed.

[SqlParameterCollection.AddWithValue Method](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.data.sqlclient.sqlparametercollection.addwithvalue(v=vs.110).aspx)

Comment: Tried out what you suggested it still throws but the exception messsage has change to "Additional information: The table type parameter '@Row' must have a valid type name."