# Use Parameters in SQL query when building query using string builder

Tags: c#, sql-server-2012

```
StringBuilder strSQL = new StringBuilder();

strSQL.Append("SELECT * FROM DataBaseName..TableName ");
strSQL.Append(" where Flag= @nameID");
strSQL.Append(" ORDER BY Flag DESC");`
```

Comment: i am using string builder to build a query.and also  i want add external  veritable using one of SQL injection Technic.plz suggest me how to complete this query.

Comment: You should not *use StringBuilder to  get the variables into your query* ... This is an issue you solve on calling your  query. How are you doing this?

Comment: then it solve by using string ???

Comment: `cmd.parameters.add("@nameID").Value = nameId`

Comment: No, you should **absolutely avoid** queries with your parameters fiddled into it. Read about *sql injection*. Keep the query and the parameters totally separated. This question gives a lot of background: http://stackoverflow.com/q/9999751/5089204

Comment: thq shnugo, zohar peled

Comment: Please put your actual question _in your question_, not in the comments.