# How does Command.Parameters.Add() prevent SQL injection? C#

Tags: c#, sql-server, sql-injection

I have now read a lot about SQL injection and trying to prevent it. I've come across several articles about how and why to use

```
Command.Parameters.Add()
```

[like explained here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9999751/difference-between-parameters-add-and-parameters-addwithvalue).

But I am still looking for an answer how and why it is preventing SQL injection.

MSDN doesn't have very much information about this.

Here is a example how I use it:

```
SqlCommand myCommand = new SqlCommand("SELECT * FROM table WHERE name = @name ", myConnection);
myCommand.Parameters.Add("@name", SqlDbType.NVarChar, 20).Value = "MaMu2";
```

Is my code even safe towards SQL injection, or am I wrong?

EDIT: main question is: how does it work internally?

Comment: Yes, your code is safe against Sql Injection.

Comment: The answer to your second question is given here: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4892166/how-does-sqlparameter-prevent-sql-injection

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The short version: 
Basically, the sql engine tearts sql parameters as placeholder for values.
This means that even if your `@Name` parameter would be `name';drop table tableName;--` you end up with a query like this:

```sql
SELECT * FROM table WHERE Name = 'name'';drop table tableName;--'
```

As apposed to if you would have concatenate strings to create the sql - that would create a query like this:

```sql
SELECT * FROM table WHERE Name = 'name';drop table tableName;--
```

As you can see, the first query is safe, while the second one is not. It allows you to add harmful code to your sql.

While if you are using parameters, your harmful code will not be treated as code.
**Important note:** If you are sending parameters to a stored procedure that use these parameters to create and run dynamic sql, you are still not safe - since it is concatenating strings inside the stored procedure.

As a side note, some database engines such as oracle will allow only one command in each execute, but can still be hacked using `name' OR 1=1` that will create

```sql
SELECT * FROM table WHERE Name = 'name' OR 1=1
```