# OleDB breaking change .NET 2.0 to 4.6.1 returning record sets

Tags: .net, database, stored-procedures, oledb, oledbdatareader

I am upgrading an old VB project (before C#) from .NET 2 to 4.6.1

It is important to note that this project is agnostic when it comes to database providers.  It uses SQL Server or Oracle merely by changing the connection string. Presumably, it will work against any other OleDB data source.  It follows that direct references to Oracle binaries must be avoided. For example, what follows is using Oracle but I can't reference Oracle.anything in source code.

**Here is my problem:**

This snippet of code executes perfectly under .NET 2.0:

````
    cmdDB.Transaction = transDB
    cmdDB.CommandText = "myPackage.MyFunction"
    cmdDB.CommandType = CommandType.StoredProcedure
    cmdDB.Parameters.Add("p_extract_key", someValue)
    cmdDB.Connection = conDB
    Try
        rdrDB = cmdDB.ExecuteReader(CommandBehavior.SingleRow)
    Catch ex As Exception
        Debug.WriteLine(ex.ToString)
        Throw ex
    End Try

    ```
    Then it uses rdrDB to read the row
````

It compiles against 4.6.1 after changing "Parameters.Add" to "Parameters.AddValue"

However, it fails with "PLS-00306: wrong number or types of arguments in call to 'MyFunction'"

The signature of the stored procedure looks like this:

```
 TYPE outcur_type is REF CURSOR;
 procedure OBJEX_PR_OFFICE(p_extract_key in varchar2, outcur out outcur_type);
```

"outcur" is of type REF_CURSOR

Guessing that there has been a breaking change that now requires me to supply an OUT paramter for the cursor, I added these lines of code before Try:

```
    Dim outCursor As New OleDbParameter
    outCursor.ParameterName = "outcur"
    outCursor.Direction = ParameterDirection.Output
    cmdDB.Parameters.Add(outCursor)
```

And now we get this:

```
Exception thrown: 'System.InvalidOperationException' in System.Data.dll
System.InvalidOperationException: String[1]: the Size property has an invalid size of 0.
   at System.Data.OleDb.OleDbParameter.BindParameter(Int32 index, Bindings bindings)
   at System.Data.OleDb.OleDbCommand.CreateAccessor()
   at System.Data.OleDb.OleDbCommand.InitializeCommand(CommandBehavior behavior, Boolean throwifnotsupported)
   at System.Data.OleDb.OleDbCommand.ExecuteCommand(CommandBehavior behavior, Object& executeResult)
   at System.Data.OleDb.OleDbCommand.ExecuteReaderInternal(CommandBehavior behavior, String method)
   at System.Data.OleDb.OleDbCommand.ExecuteReader(CommandBehavior behavior)
```

I have spent several hours tring various combinations of parameter values.  It appears to me that setting the outCursor parameter's DbType to type DbType.Cursor or OleDBType.Cursor might help but no types like that seem to exist.

I could alter the app to define an interface and create implementations for different database providers and avoid OleDB.  But before I inform my client that the cost of their project is about to explode, I thought I would ask the community for ideas.

Any thoughts regarding what to do next?

Comment: "I could alter the app to define an interface and create implementations for different database providers and avoid OleDB" - this is unfortunately inevitable unless your program uses only the most trivial of queries. Different RDBMS all have their own unique _and incompatible_ SQL dialects that mean using OLE-DB  in an attempt to be compatible with a plurality of DB engines only a distant dream. This is also why everyone loves Entity Framework (because Linq abstracts away SQL, provided the table schemas are compatible).

Comment: I see you're storing the queries inside stored-procedures - in that case you probably can get-away with using OLE-DB. For this specific piece of code you need to add a Parameter for the output parameter. It looks like in .NET Framework 2.0 you didn't need to provide an explicit parameter for the `out` cursor parameter - but now you do. If you're just ignoring the parameter could you use `Variant` as the type?

Comment: @Dai You are correct, fairly trivial queries.  However, if you think things through and stay close to ANSI you would be amazed what non-trivial things can be accomplished.  Avoiding traps created by proprietary features affords a little freedom abuse by licencors.  In any event, this project was designed in 2003.  It was rewritten in 2004-2005 after Microsoft basically made .NET 1.1 useless. Since then it has processed a few billion transactions against Oracle and SQL Server, same binary.  I would hate to rewrite it due to this problem.

Comment: See if this offers any clues: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9999751/difference-between-parameters-addstring-object-and-parameters-addwithvalue