# Inserting a List of Data results in a connection error

Tags: c#, sql-server, list, ado.net, sqlcommand

I am trying to enter a list of data objects to my table using a loop. But during the loop, the logic abruptly stops with this error:

> There is already an open DataReader associated with this Command which must be closed first.

Here's my code:

```
List<TransactionAccount> accounts = new List<TransactionAccount>();

try
   {
        using (con = new SqlConnection(connectionString))
        {
            string query = "INSERT INTO Accounts (name, category) VALUES (@name, @category)";
            cmd = new SqlCommand(query, con);
            con.Open();
    
            foreach (TransactionAccount account in accounts)
            {
                cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@name", account.name);
                cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@category", account.category);
                int exec = cmd.ExecuteNonQuery();
            }
    
            con.Close();
        }
    }
    catch (Exception ex)
    {
                    
    }
```

The error doesn't make sense because I close the connection at the end of the loop. What should I change here?

Comment: when do you see this error? inside the foreach loop? or during the foreach loop? How many times the loop iterate before the error?

Comment: The error message clearly indicates a **DataReader** is open and causing a disturbance in the force, which may mean one was left open elsewhere.  `AddWithValue`  wont work well in a loop.  An empty catch is also a bad idea

Comment: where and how is `cmd ` declared?

Comment: You ought to populate a `DataTable` with all the data and then save it all in a single batch by calling `Update` on a data adapter. [Here](https://www.vbforums.com/showthread.php?469872-Retrieving-and-Saving-Data-in-Databases&p=3112830&viewfull=1#post3112830)'s one I prepared earlier.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I would suggest to instead of calling the query again and again, better pass a table variable. it will save multiple calls to the database query. and will improve the performance of your code.

you can write a store procedure which would take the table variable as a parameter.

and in the stored procedure, you can run a loop for this table variable and insert the records.

And coming to your original question, I suspect you have declared `cmd`   as a class member and using it across multiple queries which are causing issues. you should declare it inside your method.

and please avoid `AddWithValue` you can use Parameters.Add, [Here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/21110001/sqlcommand-parameters-add-vs-addwithvalue) is why?

Also, Please utilize the return value of `ExecuteNonQuery` like logging it.

Comment: You were right. I was reusing another cmd. As for AddWithValue, isn't .Add deprecated? Thanks for your feedback!

Comment: @Jay please refer to this https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9999751/difference-between-parameters-addstring-object-and-parameters-addwithvalue