# Exception when calling ExecuteNonQuery with 0 argument(s): "The multi-part identifier "System.Data.DataRow.id" could not be bound."

Tags: sql-server, postgresql, powershell, t-sql

I am trying with this script to query and collect data from a Postgres server and then load this data in a table `DatenBankTable`. After that i want to insert this collected information in a table in a SQL Server [this is the table in the SQL Server](https://i.stack.imgur.com/1YT3C.png). So it's basically data migration from Postgres to SQL Server.

```
#### connection to the Postgres server######
$MyServer = "H01POSxxx"
$MyPort  = "5xx"
$MyDB = "daxx"
$MyUid = "akxx"
$MyPass = "xxxx"

$PgConnectionString = "Driver={PostgreSQL Unicode(x64)};Server=$MyServer;Port=$MyPort;Database=$MyDB;Uid=$MyUid;Pwd=$MyPass;"
$PgConn = New-Object System.Data.Odbc.OdbcConnection;
$PgConn.ConnectionString = $PgConnectionString;
$PgConn.Open();

#######connection to the SQL Server#########

$SqlConnecting = "Server=h01sqlxx\insxx;Database=KPIs_DBInxxx;Integrated Security= True;Connect Timeout=30";
$SqlConn = new-object System.DATA.Sqlclient.sqlconnection;
$SqlConn.ConnectionString = $SqlConnecting;
$SqlCommand = $SqlConn.CreateCommand();
$SqlConn.open();

#############query the data from the Postrgres server############

$DatenBankQuery = $PgConn.CreateCommand();
$DatenBankQuery.CommandText = "

SELECT pg_database.oid AS ID,
pg_database.datname AS Datenbank,
(pg_stat_file('base/'||pg_database.oid ||'/PG_VERSION')).modification AS Erstellt,
pg_size_pretty(pg_database_size(datname)) AS Datenbankgröße,
pg_database.datcollate AS Collation,
pg_shdescription.description AS Beschreibung,
joblog.jlgstart AS Backup
from pg_database LEFT JOIN pg_shdescription
ON pg_database.oid = pg_shdescription.objoid,
pgagent.pga_job jobs
LEFT JOIN pgagent.pga_joblog joblog
ON jobs.jobid = joblog.jlgjobid
WHERE jobs.jobname LIKE '%BACKUP%'
AND joblog.jlgstatus = 's'
AND joblog.jlgstart = (SELECT MAX(jlgstart) from pgagent.pga_joblog) "

######Execute the queries and load the data in the table "DatenBankTable"#########

$DatenBankAdapter = New-Object System.Data.Odbc.OdbcDataAdapter($DatenBankQuery)
$DatenBankTable = New-Object System.Data.DataTable
$null = $DatenBankAdapter.Fill($DatenBankTable)

##### insert the data in the table "postgres.DATABASE_TABLE" on the SQL Server########

foreach($tab in $DatnBankTable) {

    $SqlCommand.CommandText = @" 

insert into postgres.DATABASE_TABLE (ID, Datenbank, Erstellt, Datenbankgröße, Collation, Beschreibung, Backups)

VALUES ($tab.id, '$tab.datenbank', '$tab.erstellt', '$tab.datenbankgröße', '$tab.collation', '$tab.beschreibung', '$tab.backup');

"@;
}

$null = $SqlCommand.ExecuteNonQuery();
```

The queries are working and the data is stored in the table `DatenBankTable`.

```
PS C:\WINDOWS\system32> $DatenBankTable

id             : 13012
datenbank      : postgres
erstellt       : 05.10.2020 13:47:37
datenbankgröße : 32 MB
collation      : German_Germany.1252
beschreibung   : default administrative connection database
backup         : 11.12.2022 00:00:03

id             : 83481
datenbank      : lrsql_db
erstellt       : 11.03.2022 13:57:31
datenbankgröße : 9549 kB
collation      : German_Germany.1252
beschreibung   : 
backup         : 11.12.2022 00:00:03

id             : 1
datenbank      : template1
erstellt       : 05.10.2020 13:47:22
datenbankgröße : 7661 kB
collation      : German_Germany.1252
beschreibung   : default template for new databases
backup         : 11.12.2022 00:00:03

id             : 13011
datenbank      : template0
erstellt       : 05.10.2020 13:47:37
datenbankgröße : 7513 kB
collation      : German_Germany.1252
beschreibung   : unmodifiable empty database
backup         : 11.12.2022 00:00:03

id             : 53356
datenbank      : CrosscapEnterprise_Q
erstellt       : 01.12.2020 13:51:20
datenbankgröße : 14 MB
collation      : German_Germany.1252
beschreibung   : 
backup         : 11.12.2022 00:00:03

id             : 86458
datenbank      : TNM_Remox_Q
erstellt       : 07.06.2022 11:22:34
datenbankgröße : 7773 kB
collation      : German_Germany.1252
beschreibung   : 
backup         : 11.12.2022 00:00:03

id             : 115715
datenbank      : Test_DB_LM
erstellt       : 03.11.2022 15:55:00
datenbankgröße : 7805 kB
collation      : German_Germany.1252
beschreibung   : TEST11
backup         : 11.12.2022 00:00:03
```

However, I get this error when trying to insert this data into SQL Server:

> Exception when calling ExecuteNonQuery with 0 argument(s): "The multi-part identifier "System.Data.DataRow.id" could not be bound."

I'm not sure what the exact problem is, but if I had to guess, I would say that the values are not being interpreted, because I have more than one table, as you can see here:

```
PS C:\WINDOWS\system32> $SqlCommand


Connection              : System.Data.SqlClient.SqlConnection
NotificationAutoEnlist  : True
Notification            : 
Transaction             : 
CommandText             : 
                          insert into postgres.DATABASE_TABLE (ID, Datenbank, Erstellt, Datenbankgröße, Collation, Beschreibung, Backups)
                          
                          VALUES (System.Data.DataRow.id, 'System.Data.DataRow.datenbank', 'System.Data.DataRow.erstellt', 'System.Data.DataRow.datenbankgröße', 'System.Data.DataRow.collation', 'System.Data.DataRow.beschreibung', 'System.Data.DataRow.backup');
                          
ColumnEncryptionSetting : UseConnectionSetting
CommandTimeout          : 30
CommandType             : Text
DesignTimeVisible       : True
Parameters              : {}
UpdatedRowSource        : Both
```

I tried to solve the problem with parameters but that doesn't work either.

```
    $SqlCommand.CommandText = @" 

insert into postgres.DATABASE_TABLE (ID, Datenbank, Erstellt, Datenbankgröße, Collation, Beschreibung, Backups)

VALUES ("@id", @da, @qw, @er, @rt, @tz, @zu);

"@;

$SqlCommand.Parameters.Add("@id", $DatenBankTable);
```

and I get this error:

> The table type parameter '@id' must have a valid type name

```
PS C:\WINDOWS\system32>   $SqlCommand.CommandText = @" 

insert into postgres.DATABASE_TABLE (ID, Datenbank, Erstellt, Datenbankgröße, Collation, Beschreibung, Backups)

VALUES ("@id", @da, @qw, @er, @rt, @tz, @zu);

"@;

$SqlCommand.Parameters.Add("@id", $DatenBankTable);

$null = $SqlCommand.ExecuteNonQuery();


CompareInfo                     : None
XmlSchemaCollectionDatabase     : 
XmlSchemaCollectionOwningSchema : 
XmlSchemaCollectionName         : 
ForceColumnEncryption           : False
DbType                          : Object
LocaleId                        : 0
ParameterName                   : @id
Precision                       : 0
Scale                           : 0
SqlDbType                       : Structured
SqlValue                        : 
UdtTypeName                     : 
TypeName                        : 
Value                           : {13012, 83481, 1, 13011...}
Direction                       : Input
IsNullable                      : False
Offset                          : 0
Size                            : 0
SourceColumn                    : 
SourceColumnNullMapping         : False
SourceVersion                   : Current

Ausnahme beim Aufrufen von "ExecuteNonQuery" mit 0 Argument(en):  "Der table-Typparameter '@id' muss einen gültigen Typnamen haben."
In Zeile:11 Zeichen:1
+ $null = $SqlCommand.ExecuteNonQuery();
+ ~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~
    + CategoryInfo          : NotSpecified: (:) [], MethodInvocationException
    + FullyQualifiedErrorId : ArgumentException
```

I am really lost and I have been trying to solve this problem for 3 days. Any help is greatly appreciated

Comment: Only the `$tab` portion of `$tab.id` is being interpreted and substituted by the Powershell string interpolation llogic. The `$tab` loop variable is of type `System.Data.DataRow` and the default `.ToString()` for that type just returns the type name. The result is that the generated SQL literally contains `System.Data.DataRow.id` and the database engine is unable to find such an object. Instead of `$tab.id`, try `$($tab.id)` and similar for the rest of the `VALUES` references. That should insert the intended value such as `13012`.

Comment: To minimally demo the Powershell behavior, consider `$s = 'abc'`. Then `"$s.Length"` would yield `"abc.Length"`, but `"$($s.Length)"` would yield `"3"`.

Comment: As you might already be aware, your initial technique for building the dynamic SQL is susceptible to SQL Injection attacks. Using parameters is the right approach to avoid this vulnerability. Instead of `.Add()`, I believe you need to use `.AddWithValue()` to define your parameters and assign the value. Something like `$SqlCommand.Parameters.AddWithValue("@id", $tab.id);` and similar for the remaining parameters. There is no need to quote string values. Also, loose the double quotes around the `@id` in the `VALUES ("@id", @da, @qw, @er, @rt, @tz, @zu)` part of your SQL

Comment: See also [Difference between Parameters.Add(string, object) and Parameters.AddWithValue](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9999751/difference-between-parameters-addstring-object-and-parameters-addwithvalue).

Comment: Figure out a way to parse out any null value `System.Data.DataRow.id` returned records. Select and look at all records and all null records to see if you get anything and see what happens if a value is null on an insert statement.

Comment: Your Select query has JOINs and your data is coming from more than one table.   The DataAdapter creates links between the database and the datatable.  The best way of solving issue is to modify the DatenBankTable with the new values.  Then use the Accept Change method to save changes back to the database instead of using an Insert command.  See c# documentation for more info : https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.data.dataset.acceptchanges?view=net-7.0&force_isolation=true.

Comment: For the accept changes to work you need to have four commands 1) Select 2) Insert 3) Update 4) Delete.  A ComandBuilder will take the Select command and build the other three.  See : https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.data.sqlclient.sqlcommandbuilder?view=dotnet-plat-ext-7.0&force_isolation=true